# angular js array of objects for select with ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a character which can contain multiple skills.
Skills are available from an injected service.
What I basically want is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in character.getSkills()">
    <select ng-model="skill" ng-options="select as s.toString() for s in getAllSkills()"></select>
    <button ng-click="character.removeSkill(skill)" >Remove Skill</button>
</div>
```

With this code, the select box doesn't work as I would expect it. Skills are not set in the character, and selections are not kept in the drop down.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
roemer

Comment: Each iteration of ng-repeat creates its own (child) scope.  Therefore, `ng-mode="skill"` will create a `skill` primitive property on the child scope, not on the scope where `character` is defined.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482 (section ng-repeat) for some ideas.

Comment: great artikle, thanks for pointing this out.
what I don't get is, that in my case, skills are objects, and not primitives. so shouldn't the skill in the ngrepeat reference the character skill..?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize each `skill` is an object.  (It would be helpful to include some more code next time.)

Answer (score 1):

After all, I'm referencing the skill in the character.skills array by the $index property in the child scope:

```
<select ng-model="character.skills[$index]" ng-options="sk as sk.toString() for sk in getAllSkills()"></select>
```